# guarded execution of recursive methods in ruby / jruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, hash, jruby

I try to better understand the behaviour of (j)ruby when invoking recursive functions. For instance, consider the following code:

```
map = Hash.new
map[map] = "foo"
puts map.hash
```

I would expect that this results in a stackoverflow as hash calls hash on the keys, and therefore is recursive. I debugged into JRuby and came across methods like ruby.safeRecurse - it looks like recursion is detected and handled differently. This is quite different to how for instance Java handles this.

My questions are: (1) is this behaviour consistent across multiple ruby implementations and (2) is there a document that describes and motivates this design choice ?

Any hint is highly appreciated !

-Jens

Comment: it works in ruby 2.3

Comment: The defintion of it is here: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/Ruby.java